# Redhat Linux enterprise kernel source code location?

Tags: linux-kernel

I have downloaded Redhat Linux Enterprise version 6.2 ISO and installed it. It’s running fine and everything looks ok; however I mounted the ISO to look for the kernel-source, or *src* rpm and I cannot seem to find it. I find the devel rpm but not the source. I also cannot seem to find it via my Redhat customer portal account online searching channels, etc.

The kernel version of the Redhat enterprise version I downloaded and have running is: 2.6.32-220.. I have found an ftp.redhat.com site, and I can get any kernel version from kernel.org; however I would prefer to get the exact kernel used by my Redhat enterprise 6.2 distribution. I thought it was on the media, the ISO but it wasn’t.

Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: I edited your question, please check the formating before submitting a question. If you don't like the changes feel free to revert or edit it again.

Answer (score 4):

ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/5Server/en/os/SRPMS/kernel-2.6.18-128.1.1.el5.src.rpm etc

You can browse the [SRPMS](ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/5Server/en/os/SRPMS/) folder

Answer (score 0):

In the intervening years this has changed every so slightly. With [RHEL 7 there's now a README](http://ftp.redhat.com/redhat/linux/enterprise/7Server/en/os/README):

> Current sources for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 have been moved to the
> following location: https://git.centos.org/project/rpms
>
> Red Hat Enterprise Linux customers can obtain the RHEL 7 SRPMS in the
> Red Hat Customer Portal: https://access.redhat.com/site/downloads/.  You
> can download them using a web browser or using yum-utils on a rhel7 system.